# Is there a way to retrieve the outcome of a Stored Procedure Unit Test from within MSTest?

Tags: unit-testing, stored-procedures, tfs, automated-tests, sql-server-data-tools

I would like to automate some of the back end validation tests within our backlog. I researched SSDT and it looks very promising. Being able to attach a Unit Test to a Stored Procedure can be very useful. My goal, if possible, would be to have an automated test within MSTest (linked to TFS) execute functionality, then call the Stored Procedure.

Is it possible to retrieve the the outcome of the Stored Procedure Unit Test from within MSTest?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2012/12/07/getting-started-with-sql-server-database-unit-testing-in-ssdt/  dated, but probably still relevant

Comment: That is very helpful! Thank you very much for the direction.

Comment: a little less dated: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851212(v=vs.103).aspx